# read() not working when called from a pthread C

Tags: c, embedded, pthreads, client, server

I am currently writing a C server with a goal of using pthreads to handle the client connections, all works perfectly fine until I introduce pthreads. I fire a client off on the pthread and it is created and ran fine; however, it will no longer 'read()' from the client's file descriptor.

I have been trying to figure this out for roughly 2 weeks now. I have included code snippets of both the server code (including and excluding pthreads.) and client handler code.

Here is my main server loop (pthreaded):

```
/*Sets up and runs the server. (MAX 10 CLIENTS)*/
void publicServer(void)
{
    //Server locals
    int serverSocket_fd;
    int clientSocket_fd;
    socklen_t serverLength;
    socklen_t clientLength;
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddress;
    struct sockaddr_in clientAddress;

    //Threading locals
    pthread_t threadPool[20];   //Pool of threads, used in a FIFO fashion.
    int threadPointer = 0;      //Points to the location of the next available thread.

    //Clear old sockets
    puts("Unlinking server socket");
    unlink("server_socket");

    //Setup server socket
    printf("Setting server socket properties..\n");
    serverSocket_fd                 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    serverAddress.sin_family        = AF_INET;
    serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr   = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serverAddress.sin_port          = htons(5000);
    serverLength = sizeof(serverAddress);

    //Bind the socket
    printf("Binding socket\n");
    bind(serverSocket_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddress, serverLength);

    //Create listener
    listen(serverSocket_fd, 20);

    //Main server loop
    printf("Entering main loop\n");
    while (1)
    {
        clientLength = sizeof(clientAddress);

        //Accept connection
        printf("Blocking for connection\n");
        clientSocket_fd = accept(serverSocket_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&clientAddress, &clientLength);

        //Handle Client
        pthread_create(&threadPool[0], NULL, clientHandler, clientSocket_fd);

        //Increment thread pointer
        threadPointer++;
        if (threadPointer == 20)
        {
            threadPointer = 0;
        }

        //End client
        close(clientSocket_fd);
    }
}
```

Here is the server code without the pthreads (Works fine.):

```
/*Sets up and runs the server. (MAX 10 CLIENTS)*/
void publicServer(void)
{
    //Server locals
    int serverSocket_fd;
    int clientSocket_fd;
    socklen_t serverLength;
    socklen_t clientLength;
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddress;
    struct sockaddr_in clientAddress;

    //Clear old sockets
    puts("Unlinking server socket");
    unlink("server_socket");

    //Setup server socket
    printf("Setting server socket properties..\n");
    serverSocket_fd                 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    serverAddress.sin_family        = AF_INET;
    serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr   = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serverAddress.sin_port          = htons(5000);
    serverLength = sizeof(serverAddress);

    //Bind the socket
    printf("Binding socket\n");
    bind(serverSocket_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddress, serverLength);

    //Create listener
    listen(serverSocket_fd, 20);

    //Main server loop
    printf("Entering main loop\n");
    while (1)
    {
        clientLength = sizeof(clientAddress);

        //Accept connection
        printf("Blocking for connection\n");
        clientSocket_fd = accept(serverSocket_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&clientAddress, &clientLength);

        //Handle Client
        clientHandler(clientSocket_fd);

        //End client
        close(clientSocket_fd);
    }
}
```

Here is the client handler code:

```
/*
 * Handles the client's request.
 * <int : client_fd> Client's file descriptor.
 */
void *clientHandler(int client_fd)
{
    char request = ' ';

    puts("Waiting for request");
    read(client_fd, &request, 1);

    //Determine what to do for user
    if (request == '1')                 //Output current temp and pressure
    {
        outputCurrentTemperaturePressure(client_fd);
    }
    else if (request == '2')            //Begin regular sampling of temp and pressure
    {
        startSampling();
    }
    else if (request == '3')            //Stop regular sampling of temp and pressure
    {
        stopSampling();
    }
    else if (request == '4')            //Clear the EEPROM
    {
        eraseEEPROM();
    }
    else if (request == '5')            //Retrieve all stored temperature and pressure values
    {
        outputSavedTempPressValues(client_fd);
    }
    else if (request == '6')            //Retrieve a certain number of temperature and pressure values
    {
        outputLastNTempPressValues(client_fd);
    }
    else if (request == '7')            //Output current noise level
    {
        outputCurrentNoiseLevel(client_fd);
    }

    close(client_fd);
    pthread_exit(1);
}
```

The issue is with line 6 in the clientHandler method when I attempt to read from the client. When ran on a pthread it reads 0 all the time. However, when ran without pthreads it reads the correct value. I hope somebody can help out with this as it is really puzzling me.

Thanks in advance,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

just close client socket_fd in thread, but not main function

```
while (1)
{
    clientLength = sizeof(clientAddress);

    //Accept connection
    printf("Blocking for connection\n");
    clientSocket_fd = accept(serverSocket_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&clientAddress, &clientLength);

    //Handle Client
    pthread_create(&threadPool[0], NULL, clientHandler, clientSocket_fd);

    //Increment thread pointer
    threadPointer++;
    if (threadPointer == 20)
    {
        threadPointer = 0;
    }

    //End client
    /* remove close(clientSocket_fd) from here */
}
```

When you run new thread in while, loop still closes cliend file descriptor and that is the reason why `read()` doesnot work

Comment: That fixes the problem of read() so thankyou for that! But now i'm stuck with a lot of pthreads all waiting. I'll have to figure something out to block the server loop.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see it the pthread entry point must have a void * argument. The way you defined the clientHandler seems wrong. Read this:
http://timmurphy.org/2010/05/04/pthreads-in-c-a-minimal-working-example/
.

Answer (score 0):

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                      void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);


pthread_create(&threadPool[0], NULL, clientHandler, (void*)&clientSocket_fd);

void *clientHandler(void *args) {
int client_fd = *((int*) args);
```